# BrowserSync custom browser

Tags: browser, microsoft-edge, browser-sync

How i can change 'browser' setting in BrowserSync to open all in Microsoft Edge Dev? I know only how to open in default Edge...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

On Mac I use...

```
// Open in Edge
browser: 'microsoft edge'

// Open in Safari and Edge
['safari', 'microsoft edge' ]
```